# How to return the rank of each double in an array when there are duplicate values?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, ranking

If my input array is (10,10,20,20,30,30,40,40,50,50) I would like a simple piece of code that would return (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10). I am trying to implement an ABC classification and I am currently using this code:

```
    For i = 1 To noA 'noA number of items should be classified as "A"
        'return the item number with the i'th largest number in arrTembABC
        intTemp = Application.Match(WorksheetFunction.Large(arrTempABC, i), arrTempABC, True)
        'assign the category "A" to 'intTemp' item number
        SKUinfo(intTemp, 12) = "A"
    Next i

    'some printing code
```

The problem with the above code is that when there are duplicate values, it always returns the position of the first instance. Any other item number with the same value does not get assigned a category.

So for the array discussed above (see "avg value") the code only classifies the first instance of each duplicate value, and the rest are blank (see "ABC_CategCry")

[image]

Comment: Using a loop to locate the position(s) would be a reasonable alternative to `Match()` and no slower

Comment: Thank you, I resorted to the code i used in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to sorting the array that holds the values while holding their positions in a separate array. I post the entire sub below that does an ABC classification based either on volume or value (=avg volume*cost). I tried to comment in an informative way but appreciate any questions for clarification or comments on how to improve clarity.

```
Sub ABCclass(ByRef swtcABCclass As Integer, ByRef prcA As Double, ByRef prcB As Double, _
    ByRef prcC As Double)
    Dim arrTempABC() As Double, i As Integer, j As Integer, intTemp As Integer, tempABC As Double
    Dim noA As Integer, noB As Integer, noC As Integer, arrTempTSno() As Integer

    ReDim arrTempABC(1 To tsTot)
    ReDim arrTempTSno(1 To tsTot)


    'populate the array that holds the values by which we classify the SKUs
    If swtcABCclass = 1 Then 'ABC based on volume*value
        For i = 1 To tsTot
            arrTempABC(i) = SKUinfo(i, 11) * SKUinfo(i, 5) 'average monthly volume*value (cost)
            arrTempTSno(i) = i 'just hold the position (ascending number of the timeseries/SKU)
        Next i
    ElseIf swtcABCclass = 2 Then 'ABC based on volume
        For i = 1 To tsTot
            arrTempABC(i) = SKUinfo(i, 11) ' average monthly volume
            arrTempTSno(i) = i
        Next i
    End If

    'find the limits of each class (in terms of percentages of SKUbase)
    noA = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(tsTot * prcA, 0) 'first prcA% of the tsTot (number of timeseries or SKUs) are in class A
    noB = noA + WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(tsTot * prcB, 0)
    noC = tsTot

    'sort arrTempABC while saving the positions in a seperate array
    For i = 2 To tsTot
        tempABC = arrTempABC(i)
        intTemp = arrTempTSno(i)
        For j = i - 1 To 1 Step -1
            If arrTempABC(j) >= tempABC Then Exit For
            arrTempABC(j + 1) = arrTempABC(j)
            arrTempTSno(j + 1) = arrTempTSno(j)
        Next
        arrTempABC(j + 1) = tempABC
        arrTempTSno(j + 1) = intTemp
    Next

    'now that i have the sorted positions, i can just assign the categories
    For i = 1 To noA 'noa number of items should be classified as "A"
        SKUinfo(arrTempTSno(i), 12) = "A"
    Next i
    For i = noA + 1 To noB 'nob - (noa +1) number of items should be classified as "B"
        SKUinfo(arrTempTSno(i), 12) = "B"
    Next i
    For i = noB + 1 To noC 'noc - (nob +1) number of items should be classified as "C"
        SKUinfo(arrTempTSno(i), 12) = "C"
    Next i

End Sub
```